# How to parse C++ comments with lark?

Tags: parser-generator, lark-parser

How can I write a rule to parse C++ comments either on a line alone or after other code?

I've tried lots of combinations, the latest one being:

```
?comment: "//" /[^\n]*/ NEWLINE
```

Answer (score 2):

You had the right idea, but you should define comments as a single terminal (i.e. not a structure), for performance, and also so you can ignore them.

```
COMMENT: "//" /[^\n]*/ NEWLINE

%ignore COMMENT
```

Example grammar:

```py
from lark import Lark

g = r"""
!start: "hello"

COMMENT: "//" /[^\n]*/ _NEWLINE
_NEWLINE: "\n"
%ignore COMMENT
%ignore " "
"""

parser = Lark(g)
print(parser.parse("hello // World \n"))
```

Comment: How would you modify this grammar to support the other form of c-style comment -- the multi-line comment e.g. `/* multi-line \n comment */`

Answer (score 1):

You simply define a terminal and then ignore it:

```
COMMENT : /\/\// /.*/
        | /\/\*/ /.*/ /\*\//

%ignore COMMENT
```

NOTE: This will work only if you'll ignore all whitespace

```
%import common.WS
%ignore WS
```

Answer (score 0):

Using: `?comment: /\/\/[^\n]*/`

Then I had to handle the comment as a lark.lexer.Token.